# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error in Expess

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
const Car = mongoose.model('Car', new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
}));


router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = joiValidator(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

  try {
    const car= await Car.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { name: req.body.name }, {new: true })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).send('not found.');
  }  
  
  res.send(car);
})
```

i am successfully connected to mongoDB using mongoose, its only when i try to mock an error by giving a wrong id as an input i get the following error, even though i handled async and await with the trycatch block

```
(node:19392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: i am using node v14.11.0

Comment: which router are you using?

Comment: const router = express.Router()

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because you are using try an catch after an if. In javascript the way of reading code is asynchronous so, if and try are executed at the same time. Also, you don´t need to use an async function here, as you are only calling one promise.

Here I let you a simpler code without async.

```
router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { error } = joiValidator(req.body);
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  } else {
    Car.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{ name: req.body.name },{ new: true },(err, car) => {
        if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Not found', err });
        return res.status(200).send(car);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: i have no problem with handling joi errors its all about handling mongodb error, like i`ve said for example giving a false id as an input in the url i dont get the error handling neither on postoman or the console, all i get is the error above

Comment: we can simply remove joi from the code all together, its about the async/await code when its not resolved